# How to get ip of current users who visit a particular article

Tags: php, blogs, article

I have table called blog with the fields id, count, headline, text and i want
to to get the n most read posts, but when a user reads an article, that is counted only once.How can this be solved using the IP address?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the superglobal variable [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/fr/reserved.variables.server.php), the field `remote_addr` contain the user IP but it isn't a secure way to count them. An other way is to count the number of user session, using the variable $_SESSION.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this thread on getting IP - [How to get the client IP address in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php)

You can add another table to your DB, let's say hits with post_id (foreign key to your blog table) and ip_address as columns.

You can follow this logic afterwards.

1. Get client IP (`$ip`) and current post ID (`$pid`)
2. Query hits table with condition - `WHERE ip_address = $ip AND post_id = $pid`
3. `IF` a row is returned that means article has been viewed from this IP so do nothing `ELSE` insert the row in table with `$ip` and `$pid`

If you need to count hits for a article, you can do a count query with post_id in where clause.